# NullPointerException for my TreeNode

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree, treenode

Here is the structure for my treenode

```
class Node{
    int value;
    Node left;
    Node right;
    public Node(int val){
        this.value=val;
    }
}
```

In main: I try constructing a tree. The root is 10 and I try adding a left subtree with value 4

```
Node sub=new Node(10);
    sub.left.value=4;     // line 1
    sub.left=new Node(4); // line 2
```

Why line 1 will not work and line 2 work?

Comment: I set the value of the node not the node to be 4 @developer033

Answer (score 1):

`left` is not initalized either when declared or in the constructor. Therefore when you call `sub.left.whatever` you get an NPE because `sub.left` is null at that point.

Reordering line 1 and 2 will help.

> Why would line 2 work on its own?

Notice that line 2 is all assignments. `sub.left` is being assigned a new node whose `value` is being assigned as `4`.

Answer (score -1):

In java, if you don't declare any constructor, JVM will create default constructor with no parameter. But if you declare constructor with parameter, JVM won't create default constructor with no parameter.
In line 1

> sub.left.value=4;
>   Your class not yet initial. So it will be null.

In line 1

> sub.left=new Node(4);

You initial class and assign value for it. So can't be null.